Unable to read socket stream in Python, gets stuck at recvfrom. Works in DotNet/Terminal
I have a device that converts analog audio to digital audio, and there's a way to listen to the stream in my local server through the UDP protocol.

Working- When in my terminal, if I run echo 'subscribe' | nc -u 192.168.0.194 9444, I receive a response for ~15 seconds shown as below which I should be able to convert to an audio that I can play:

?a?????̻?yyzzyyzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}|||}|}~~~~~~~~~~~}~~~~~~}}~~~}}}}}|||||}|||||||||||}|||||||||||{{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzz?a???p?̻?zzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzywxxxxxwwxxxxxxxxxxxyyyzzyyzyyyyyyyyyzzzyyyyzzzzzzzzz{zz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{|{|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||?a???P?̻?||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}||||}|}~~~~~~~~~~~}~~~~~~}}}}~~~}}}}|||||}||||||||||||||||||{|||{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?a???0?̻?yyyzzzzzzzzzzyzzzyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxwwwxxxxwwxxxxxxxxxxyyyzyyyyyyyyyyzzzyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzz{zz{z{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}~~~~~~~~~~?a???̻?~~~~}}~~~~~}}}}}}}}}}|||{|}|||||||||}}|||||||{|||{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxyyyyyyyyyyyzyyyyzzzzzzzzyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxwwwxxxxwwxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzyxy?a????̻?yyzzyyzzzzzzzzzzzz{z{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}||||||}~~~~~~~~~~~~~}}}~~~~~}}~}}}}}}}||{|}|||||||||||||||||{{||{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz?a????̻?zzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxwwxxxxxwxxxxxxxxxxxyyyzyyzyyyyyyzzzyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||?a?İ?̻?||||||||||||||||||||{||{|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}||||}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}}}~~~~}}}||||{|}||||||||||||||||||||||{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyyzy?a?Ɛ?̻?zzzzzzzzzzzzyyzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxwxxxxwwwxxxxxxxxxxxyyyzyyyyyyyyyzzzyyyyyzyyzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{|{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||~~~~~~~~~~?a??p?̻?~~~}}}~~~~~~~~}}}}}}}||{|}||||||||||||}}||{{|||{|{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxwxxxxwwwxxxxxxxxxxxyyyzyyyyyyzyyyyzzzz?a??P?̻?yyyyyzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}||||}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}}}}}~~}}}}||||{|}|||||||||||||||||{||{|{{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz?a??0?̻?zzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxyyyyyyyyyyyyzyyzzzzzzzzzyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzywwwxxyyxxwxxxxxxxxxxyyyzyyzyyyyyyzzzyyyyzyyyzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||????̻?|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}|}}}~~~~~~~~~~~}~~~~~~}}~~~}}}}}|||||}|||}|||||||||||||||||||{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzz?a  ????̻?zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzywwwxxyyxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzyyzyyyyyyzzzzyyyzzzyyzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}||}}}~~~~~~~?a...


Working- I get a similar response when I try to run it in C#:

async Task StartListener(){
     UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(9444);
     IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.194"), 9444);
     byte[] requestMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("subscribe");
     await listener.SendAsync(requestMessage, requestMessage.Length, groupEP);
     while (true){            
            await listener.SendAsync(requestMessage, requestMessage.Length, groupEP);
            var udpReceiveResult = await listener.ReceiveAsync(); //Waiting for broadcast
            byte[] bytes = udpReceiveResult.Buffer;
            Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {groupEP} : {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)}");


Not working- In Python, I use the following script but it times out at the receive function, even though Wireshark shows UDP packets (of a similar kind to the Working instances) being initiated and sent from that device, to my laptop correctly. Not sure what's wrong with my code

import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(b"subscribe", ("192.168.0.194", 9444))
sock.connect(("192.168.0.194", 9444)) # Keeping this seems to make no difference
sock.settimeout(5)

try:
    while True:
        print("Stream receiving.") # Receive data from UDP
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # <-GETS STUCK HERE, then times out
        print(data) # Doesnt land here, prints nothing
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:    
    sock.close() # Stream stopping
print("Stream closed and socket closed.")

Unhelpful Error message, since without adding the timeout, it just stay stuck at the sock.recvfrom line and does nothing, even after the device has stopped sending data:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saamer/Documents/GitHub/api/a2.py", line 11, in <module>
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # Buffer size is ?? bytes
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: timed out


Possibly useful information:
Eventually I want to be able to do something like this to play the audio. I tried to ask this question to chatGPT and the only thing it suggested was to change the value inside recvfrom(), which I did to 1 million with no positive results


I had to change all the code before to this exact order:
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 9444)) # Throws an error if it's anything else
sock.sendto(b"subscribe", ("192.168.0.194", 9444)
try:
...

and the rest of the code worked. Still don't know how I figured that out. But basically 0.0.0.0 allows listening to all packets from that port, and it wouldn't allow me to bind to 192.168.0.194

The explicit bind to 0.0.0.0:9444 is basically what the C# code does with new UdpClient(9444). But this is not what nc does. You've tried (and failed)  a sendto, followed by connect - please do instead a connect followed by a send (not sendto, since the destination is set by connect already). This order should make sure that the socket will receive the data on the same local IP:port which was used for sending the subscribe.

@SteffenUllrich I just tried sock.connect(("192.168.0.194", 9444)) and then sock.send(b"subscribe") instead of bind and sendto but it didn't work.

I got an audio signal with my code, but got no audio when I changed to yours
